# Where should I alloc/init my ivar?

Tags: iphone, initialization, allocation, instance-variables

If I know that I'm going to use the ivar should I alloc/init it in viewDidLoad like:

```
if (allPeople_ == nil)
  self.allPeople = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[selectedObject people] allObjects]];
```

or should I create a getter method and alloc/init in there:

```
- (Group *)allPeople {

    if (allPeople_ != nil)
        return allPeople_;

    allPeople_ = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[[selectedObject people] allObjects]];
    return allPeople_;
}
```

I'm assuming the getter method, with the if-statement, is for lazy-loading, which in my case I wouldn't need to do because I'm definitely using self.allPeople throughout my code.

**Extra Question:**

If I use the getter method do I actually have to do it this way?

```
allPeople_ = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:[[selectedObject people] allObjects]] retain];
```

Comment: For the Extra Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924463/how-is-retain-setter-implemented-with-synthesize/3925204#3925204

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say getter, not setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would initialize it whenever you are going to use it.

As for the second question, it depends on how your property is declared if it is declared as `retain`, and you set it like this:

```
self.allPeople =
```

you will not have to send it a retain message, because the synthetized setter will take care of that for you.

Do notice `self.allPeople` is different than just `allPeople`, if you don't use self you are not accessing it thru the `setter`, you are accesing the `ivar directly` and therefore it won't receieve a `retain` message.

Comment: So you never initialize ivars in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear? You always create getters?

Comment: @Tazboy I initialize them whenever it is needed, and no I usually don't initialize using getters unless I want to do lazy loading. viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear are good places for initialization, but  that doesn't mean you should always initialize there, you should initialize wherever it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to make your NSArray an NSMutableArray that way you can alloc init it in your init call. Use property declarations to synthesize your getters and setters. As for putting the people in your array, you can add them to the mutable array every time one is selected